# Is there a way to disable info window on xamarin.forms.maps on iOS project?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I want to disable info window on the pins in xamarin.forms.maps ? Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code about remove the info window in map you can add it in the method
you want to use

```
   nativeMap.DidDeselectAnnotationView += OnDidDeselectAnnotationView;
     void OnDidDeselectAnnotationView(object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs e)
            {
                if (!e.View.Selected)
                {
                    customPinView.RemoveFromSuperview();
                    customPinView.Dispose();
                    customPinView = null;
                }
        }
```